# DataWeave unflatten mapping

Tags: mule, dataweave

Need some help in writing DataWeave for this Salesforce payload.
Please help with creating a DataWeave for this input and expected output.

**INPUT**

```
[
    {
        "Order": {
            "Account_Name__c": "test danish 002",
            "Id": "8018s000004mpqjAAA",
            "type": "Order"
        },
        "UnitPrice": "13.45",
        "Product2": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": "Product2",
            "Name": "* 1 LEG FOR MESAHORNO STAND110"
        },
        "Id": "8028s000000kyUDAAY",
        "type": "OrderItem",
        "OrderItemNumber": "0000051590"
    },
    {
        "Order": {
            "Account_Name__c": "test danish 002",
            "Id": "8018s000004mpqjAAA",
            "type": "Order"
        },
        "UnitPrice": "308.45",
        "Product2": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": "Product2",
            "Name": "* 2 Uprights incl castors f RTWZ 600 Var"
        },
        "Id": "8028s000000kyUEAAY",
        "type": "OrderItem",
        "OrderItemNumber": "0000051591"
    },
    {
        "Order": {
            "Account_Name__c": "test danish 002",
            "Id": "8018s000004mpqjAAA",
            "type": "Order"
        },
        "UnitPrice": "31.0",
        "Product2": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": "Product2",
            "Name": "* 25 Comp Glass Rack - 3 Ext - Red Base"
        },
        "Id": "8028s000000kyUFAAY",
        "type": "OrderItem",
        "OrderItemNumber": "0000051592"
    },
    {
        "Order": {
            "Account_Name__c": "test danish 002",
            "Id": "8018s000004mpqjAAA",
            "type": "Order"
        },
        "UnitPrice": "31.65",
        "Product2": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": "Product2",
            "Name": "* 36 Comp Glass Rack 3 Ext - Gray"
        },
        "Id": "8028s000000kyUGAAY",
        "type": "OrderItem",
        "OrderItemNumber": "0000051593"
    }
]
```

This is the Salesforce Query on OrderLineItems but the transformed payload needs to be done on Order Object
and the output would look like 
**Output**

```
{
    "Id":"8018s000004mpqjAAA",
    "Order Name": "test danish 002",
    "Line Items": [
        {
            "Id":"8028s000000kyUDAAY",
            "ItemNumber":"0000051590",
            "Name":"* 1 LEG FOR MESAHORNO STAND110"
        },
        {
            "Id":"8028s000000kyUEAAY",
            "ItemNumber":"0000051591",
            "Name":"* 2 Uprights incl castors f RTWZ 600 Var"
        },
        {
            "Id":"8028s000000kyUFAAY",
            "ItemNumber":"0000051592",
            "Name":"* 25 Comp Glass Rack - 3 Ext - Red Base"
        },
        {
            "Id":"8028s000000kyUGAAY",
            "ItemNumber":"0000051593",
            "Name":"* 36 Comp Glass Rack 3 Ext - Gray"
        }
    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all the order IDs are same you can just map the `Id` directly from payload and use the `map` on `payload` to get the `Line Items`

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  Id: payload[0].Order.Id,
  "Order Name": payload[0].Order.Account_Name__c,
  "Line Items": payload map {
     Id: $.Id,
     ItemNumber: $.OrderItemNumber,
     Name: $.Product2.Name
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"Id" : payload[0].Order.Id,
"Order Name": payload[0].Order.Account_Name__c,
"Line Items" : payload map{ 
    Id: $.Id,
    ItemNumber : $.OrderItemNumber,
    "Line Items" : $.Product2.Name
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option that you can try when ordered Id's are not the same

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Order.Id) 
    mapObject ((value, key, index) ->  
            {"Id": value.Order.Id[0], 
            "Order Name": value.Order.Account_Name__c[0],
            "Line Items": value map ({
                                Id: $.Id, 
                                ItemNumber: $.OrderItemNumber,
                                Name: $.Product2.Name
 
                            })}
)
```

[image]

Comment: The first option seems to be the same as the other ones, right? The second is much more interesting because it seems that it generalizes the solution to when the order ids are not the same. I recommend to remove the first option and just leave the second one as an original solution.

Comment: @Aled yes i have edited as per your recommendation